# configure svn to use ldap with svn+ssh

Tags: linux, svn, ssh, ldap

I'd like to setup a svn server on a linux box with the following constraints :

- users will access the svn using command line
- users will use a svn+ssh protocol ( no http server on the box)
- all users are authenticated using our open ldap server

Of course the target server has no local users, only ldap users are allowed to use it.

And of course the server has the ldap authentification already configured up for all users.

Most of the topics I've checked in order to find some help all focus on apache DAV configuration.

However we'd like the svn to be available only using the command line tools and we don't want to have access using a an apache http server.

So is there a way of configuring the svn server (not apache) in order to use :

- ldap direclty ?
- use local authetication without re-declaring users and passwords ? ( especially passwords ? )

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated !

Thank in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use SVN+SSH, then basically users will be authenticated using PAM. If pam_ldap is configured properly (as you state in your initial questions) then you don't need to configure SVN server to use ldap (I'm not even sure that's possible).

Same as to local authentication, pam_ldap should take care of that.

Comment: Finally find out 1 minutes after your post ;). Thnx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies,

However this questions does not really make sense, as a default installation of svn will **use local authentication** if all the configuration files are kept in default state.

In my use case, as the server already uses LDAP for user auth, there is NOTHING to do in terms of configuration.

So maybe the real answer would be : **simply configure your svn server host to use ldap**

Sorry for the pollution, but I was confused at a given point of my tests.